# How to rename an iOS 8 Today Widget?

Tags: ios, rename, ios8-today-widget

I've just started experimenting with adding an iOS 8 Today Widget to my app, it's going ok so far but I followed the original template and got my widget created with TodayWidget as its name. In the context of my app's files in Xcode that target/product name is fine. But sadly this is the name that also displays within notification centre, above my widget.

I've tried tracing through various names in my project that match what's being displayed but so far I've yet to find one that lets me update the name displayed.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Select your widget under Project -> Targets.  Under Info -> iOS Target Properties, change the `Bundle display name` attribute to whatever you want your new name to be.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Restart the device to see the updated widget name.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

I'd tried updating this and other display name fields elsewhere in Xcode with no success. Updating the name as you describe also doesn't work, but then I thought. Perhaps iOS doesn't update the display name once its been added. I tried removing the widget and re-adding, that didn't help. However, removing and reinstalling the app did make the widget's name update to whatever's set here. So yes, just make sure you get it right before that first run, or be prepared to change it via an uninstall later. Thanks so much! Cheers!

Answer (score 11):

The answer from JAL is correct, but as my comment mentions under his answer. Don't expect a widget's name to update once it's been added to iOS. You must remove and reinstall your app to get any widget name updates to apply. I presume it's the same thing for app names too. Cheers

Answer (score 7):

Just restart the device to display the updated name!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: You're right @JAL , this response should be merged with yours.