# Rename Today widget title

Tags: ios, swift, widget, ios11, today-extension

I've added widget 'Today' in my project, which is showing a widget target name (in UPPERCASE) as widget title.

How can I change the title of widget 'Today' (I cannot change/rename widget target name as a title of the widget)?

Here is a ref snapshot:

Project Source:

[image]

Widget title in device:

[image]

Edit (According to [Harvant S.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2071323/harvant-s))
Here is info.plist for widget

[image]

Which info should be required to change here. Do you mean 'TimeTracker' a bundle name? Will it effect on any other settings of project/widget, if I change it?

Comment: It should be in `info.plist` of extension.

Comment: @HarvantS. Pl suggest me exact solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26130183/2071323 look here

Comment: @HarvantS. I've similar kind of information in info.plist but still it shows uppercase. How did they guys manage it?

Comment: If you changed the name and its not appearing as you entered, i will suggest you to restart the device in your case, restart the simulator. Please remove the existing app before restating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the target's `General` tab and change the `Display Name`.

The problem is that I don't think you can change to lower case. Whatever you input will be displayed in all caps.

Comment: iOS calender widget shows sentence case (First character in upper case title only) title. Is there any way to do it.

Comment: @Krunal Are you sure? I just checked it and it's all caps too. iPhone 7 Plus iOS 11.1

Comment: I didn't check it in device with iOS 11, but I saw that here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/26130183/2071323

Answer (score 0):

go to GENERAL and go to display name 
is changing in simulator or iphone but not changing in xcode for changing in xcode 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35500038/7110147